# Is it possible to modify the authenticate fields in OAuth authentication for spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am using spring security in my spring boot application. Currently we have option to generate token using username and password. Now i need to modify the options like i want username as email and password as mobile number. Is it possible to use like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have an option for use custom values. For example check the below code,

```html
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;  
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;  
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;  
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;  
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;  

import sunbox.dao.IUserDAO;
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  

@Service  
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {  

 @Autowired
 private IUserDAO iuserDAO;

 @Autowired
 public CustomUserDetailsService(IUserDAO iuserDAO) {
  this.iuserDAO = iuserDAO;
 } 

 @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
 @Override  
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {  
  sunbox.domain.User usr = iuserDAO.getUserByEmail(s);  

  if (usr == null) {  
   throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User details not found with this username: " + s);  
  } 

  String username = usr.getEmail();  
  String password = usr.getMobile();  
  String role = usr.getUserType().getUserTypeName();

  List authList = getAuthorities(role);  
   
  User user = new User(username, password, authList);    
  return user;  
 }  

 @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
 private List getAuthorities(String role) {  
  List authList = new ArrayList();  
  authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));       
  if (role != null && role.trim().length() > 0) {  
   if (role.equals("admin")) {  
    authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));  
   }  
  }    
  return authList;  
 }  
}
```